# Console2: Window size not detected correctly for some apps

Tags: console2

I installed Gow and am using plink to SSH into remote servers. The problem is, when I attempt to edit a file remotely with Vim, it doesn't utilize the entire screen's space. I changed the original command prompt's size via View > Console Window but that changed nothing.

Also, the escape key isn't sent to the remote server. So it's nearly impossible to edit files (I've had to use the old Ctrl+[ trick in Vim to get out of editing mode).

Another oddity is that if I am on the last line in the window, and attempt to go down one line in the buffer, it only updates the last line. The above text doesn't get updated.

When I attempt to use PuTTY (on its own), that is included with Gow, it works fine. When I attempt to use Vim locally it also works fine. Maybe there's some command that I need to send to plink? OR maybe there is something I would set in the .vimrc file? I was able to force the window size of Vim (on the remote server) by setting 'set lines=50' and 'set columns=180' but this is not ideal. And the single line scrolling issue is also still there.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? Does Gow include `xterm`, `urxvt`, or MinTTY? Or does Console2 itself support terminal emulation nowadays?

Comment: I've experienced that problem with plink and console2 as well, and I'm afraid I don't have an answer. I tried running it through ansicon to console2 as well, which solved the screen space issue, but introduced even worse problems.  Eventually I had better luck using [this Windows port of OpenSSH](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/download/) through console2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY works, because it includes a full terminal emulator along with a SSH client. However, `plink` is designed for raw data transfer, not interactive use, and does not send the tty dimensions to the server (nor does it interpret the ANSI escape sequences).

Comment: This make sense. What I ended up doing to fix it is call: putty -load ENV -l user -new_console. The -new_console being the important flag. Now it attaches a PuTTY terminal session as a tab which is _awesome_. This solves all of my remaining problems with the editor.

Comment: `-new_console` in ConEmu's feature )

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of Gow's ssh client. ConEmu's user had [similar problem](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=835) which was fixed after switching to "proper" ssh client (Git ssh AFAIK).

And try ConEmu as alternative console? (I'm the author)

Comment: "Git ssh" is a Cygwin port of OpenSSH. Cygwin has a terminal emulation layer that transparently converts between ANSI sequences and Windows console API.

Comment: @grawity ConEmu is terminal that supports ANSI sequences internally and much more (tabs, splits, quake-style, macros, default terminal and more and more)